# PhpStorm disable "Local History" and "Go to file" after implement webpack watch option

Tags: webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

My Local History on JS files are disabled after implementing webpack watch.

[image]

Also, PhpStorm fast file search option "Go to file" (on keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd>) does not search `public` folder which is under webpack watcher.

#### Webpack config file

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode:'development',
    entry: './public/app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    watch:true
};
```

How to configure PhpStorm to continue work as usual?

- My webpack version 4.26.
- PhpStorm version 2017.3.1

Answer (score 2):

PhpStorm auto-excludes webpack build target directory from indexing for better performance; as you have

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
```

in your webpack configuration file, `public` folder is excluded from project, so no navigation, etc. is possible.

To get rid of the issue, try setting webpack configuration path value (**Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**) to empty string and re-start the IDE